# extension of analytic to meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

could any one help me to show that any $f$ analytic in the annulus $1\le |z|\le 2$ and $|f|$ is a constant on $|z|=1$ and on $|z|=2$ (not necessarily the same constant) admits a meromorphic extension to $\mathbb{C}^*$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extension is given by repeated analytic reflection. Reflection (inversion) in the circle of radius $R$ is given by $\tau_R(z) = R^2/\bar{z}$. So if $|f(z)|=R$ for $|z|=2$, you can define $f(z) = \tau_R \circ f \circ \tau_2 (z)$ for $2<|z|\le 4$. (The reflected images of zeros become poles, so instead of an analytic function you only get a meromorphic function in general.) Repeated reflection in the outer circle gives a meromorphic map in $|z| \ge 1$. Reflection in the unit circle then gives you a meromorphic map in the punctured plane.